# Web Service Returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using web service exposed from govt. website to submit my client transaction and get the response back.i'm passing correct parameters to webservice in the correct formats the same webservice with the exact same parameter is working when I'm using testing tool SOAPUI but when I'm running through my c# code getting the Error.Below is the signature of web service function :

int WebSvcFunction(string login,string pwd,string xmlClaimInput,out string xmlDRGDetails,out byte[] auditFileContent,out byte[] reportFileContent,out string errorMessage);

Can anyone Correct me what's wrong I'm doing?

Below is my code onbutton click  :

```
            private void btnTestService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            try
            {
            string xmlDRGDetails = (string)null;
            byte[] auditFileContent = (byte[])null;
            byte[] reportFileContent = (byte[])null;
            string errorMessage = (string)null;

            int m = objWebservicesSoapClient.WebSvcFunction(gstrLoginId, gstrpwd, rTxtDrgTab.Text.ToString(), out xmlDRGDetails,
                                                       out auditFileContent , out reportFileContent, out errorMessage);

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Success {0}", m));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Source: {0}\nDescription:{1}\nTarget Site:{2}\nCall Stack:{3}", (object)ex.Source, (object)ex.Message, (object)ex.TargetSite, (object)ex.StackTrace), "Convert DRG", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            }
```

Comment: Without code,neither we can help not correct you.Show us where exactly at which line it's failing.

Comment: @HameedSyed I have added my piece of code being called on button click.

Comment: @HameedSyed exception is coming on call of webservice function,while exactly same thing is working on SOAP UI

Comment: Any update guys on this query?

Comment: Which is the government website?What is its output?What is it expecting as input.?

Comment: @HameedSyed can you share your mail id, so that I can communicate there along with my testing code and API documentation.

Comment: please check your kshameed7@gmail.com mail id.

Comment: @HameedSyed did you received my mail?